# Magento 2 : InvalidArgumentException

Tags: magento2

Tried this

```
composer require hubbox/magento2:3.0.1 --no-update
```

Got error in terminal

[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find a matching version of package hubbox/magento2. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches your minim
um-stability (stable).

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests you need to check if the spelling, version & minimum-stability of the package is correct.
For the stability part:
If the package doesn't have a stable version then you may need to change the `minimum-stability`to dev in `composer.json`
Please check https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability